# boost: read_json: reading multiple lines

Tags: c++, json, boost

When reading the below JSON data, am getting invalid code sequence exception 
in read_json.

```
{
   "_ID":"18",
   "_Record":"1",
   "_BreakPageMessage":"abcd: 137
     Product: ID: 1234
     Description: 23456 abcdfm
     CustomerId: 23456
     Component Id: 3456
     Description: 12345 Admn RC - up
     count: 40
     Sides 2
     Tarnish:
     size: 125 x 205
    Memo:"
}
```

_BreakPageMessage property has multiple lines. If we give it as single line everything works fine.
This _BreakPageMessage doesn't have any umlaut characters.

```
boost::property_tree::read_json( file, pt );
```

Can anyone tell is there anyway to read json that has multiple lines of property data using boost.We are using C++ and boost.

Answer (score 2):

Newlines are [not valid characters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) in JSON strings, your data *isn't JSON*.

You could escape them

```
{
   "_ID":"18",
   "_Record":"1",
   "_BreakPageMessage":"abcd: 137\r\n     Product: ID: 1234\r\n     Description: 23456 abcdfm\r\n     CustomerId: 23456\r\n     Component Id: 3456\r\n     Description: 12345 Admn RC - up\r\n     count: 40\r\n     Sides 2\r\n     Tarnish:\r\n     size: 125 x 205\r\n    Memo:"
}
```

or use a sub-object

```
{
   "_ID":"18",
   "_Record":"1",
   "_BreakPageMessage":{
      "abcd": 137,
      "Product": { "ID": 1234 },
      "Description": "23456 abcdfm",
      "CustomerId": "23456",
      "Component Id": "3456",
      "Description": "12345 Admn RC - up",
      "count": "40",
      "Sides": "2",
      "Tarnish": { size: "125 x 205" },
      "Memo":""
   }
}
```

Comment: Besides, Boost PropertyTree is not a JSON library.